# using mysql driver for work with external mysql database from GAE Application

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, playframework

I'm using GAE plugin in Play framework application, it works fine. Also i'm using MySQL driver to access external database. After i'm upload my application in GAE, mysql driver can't start to work:

Execution exception
NoClassDefFoundError occured : Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)

Is GAE not support to work MySQL driver in different thread ?

Answer (score 3):

On app engine you can not open a socket. This is why your JDBC driver is failing.

There are several other options you can consider:

- Use the GAE Big Table for storage
- Use the Hosted SQL that app engine provides (this is mysql as well)
- If you need the external MySQL for some reason, you will have to write an HTTP wrapper for your data calls and call that from app engine with the url fetch service

You may also want to read up on the play framework support for app engine: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/gae

Comment: I'm using BigTable to store only objects of my application. But my application need to work with MySql database, only SELECT data. I can't import over 10Gb of MySql data to BigTable. And if import complete, sync with real mysql database will be very hard. If GAE Application can be WEB Service, or WEB Service client, why it can't open socket ???

Comment: @user975287 that's a restriction on GAE, complain to Google :) You can't open a jdbc socket because it's blacklisted. You can only do http requests. I believe GAE is not a good platform for your project.

Comment: as I said before if you want your app to run on app engine build a webservice around your mysql and call it from gae or import the data from mysql into big table

Comment: Why can't you import over 10GB of data into Bigtable? That's what it's built for. And "webservice" implies "web" - opening sockets is not part of that.